# How do I filter Microsoft Edge history search result by specific website?

Tags: browser, search, microsoft-edge, history, browsing

How do I filter Microsoft Edge history search result by specific website? For example, only show results from youtube dot com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe the user interface will let you do much better than just entering in the site name. So you can start with `edge://history/all?q=youtube.com`.

To get better, you'll have to poke around Edge internals.
The good news is that the browser history appears to be stored in a SQLite database in a [known location](https://www.foxtonforensics.com/browser-history-examiner/microsoft-edge-history-location).

Popular free tools/links that may help you:

- Nirsoft's [BrowserHistoryView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/browsing_history_view.html)
- Foxton Forensic's [Browser History Viewer](https://www.foxtonforensics.com/browser-history-viewer/)